# In Google Charts, how can I use a header row in arrayToDataTable and also have options for the same chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I am using ajax to create a DataTable with the first row containing header information, including data type.  I am trying to have my hAxis be seen as datetime data type.  After many hours, I have discovered that if you include options, it will ignore any info in the header row of the  DataTable.  I copied a simple example to prove this theory.

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawCharts);


var options = {
    title: 'Test Graph',
        curveType: 'function',
        legend: { position: 'top' },
        width: 1300,
        height: 300
}

function drawCharts(){
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
       [ {label: 'Year', id: 'year'},
         {label: 'Sales', id: 'Sales', type: 'number'}, // Use object notation to explicitly specify the data type.
         {label: 'Expenses', id: 'Expenses', type: 'number'} ],
       ['2014', 1000, 400],
       ['2015', 1170, 460],
       ['2016', 660, 1120],
       ['2017', 1030, 540]]);

        console.log('chart-container class: ' + $('#chart-container').prop('class'))
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-container'));
        var chart_div = document.getElementById('chart-container')

        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
            chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
            //console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
        });

        chart.draw(data, options);  
}
```

If you simply take out the "options" parameter from the draw.chart function, you will get the header row specified.  With the "options", it ignores it.  There does not seem to be a way to specify the  data type through the hAxis options.  I need to be able to do that AND provide options.

Answer (score 0):

the options do not affect the data type of the data table columns.
the data type of the x-axis, or hAxis,
is driven by the data type of the first data table column.

here, no data type for the first column is being specified, only label and id.

```
{label: 'Year', id: 'year'}
```

when no type is specified, `arrayToDataTable` assigns the type based on the data provided.
in this case, the values are strings, so the data type of the x-axis will be string.

```
['2014', 1000, 400],
['2015', 1170, 460],
['2016', 660, 1120],
```

if you want the x-axis to be of type datetime,
then you need to provide actual datetime values in the data.

```
[new Date(2014, 0), 1000, 400],
[new Date(2015, 0), 1170, 460],
[new Date(2016, 0), 660, 1120],
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var options = {
    title: 'Test Graph',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: {position: 'top'},
    width: 1300,
    height: 300
  }

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    [{label: 'Year', id: 'year'},
     {label: 'Sales', id: 'Sales', type: 'number'},
     {label: 'Expenses', id: 'Expenses', type: 'number'}],
    [new Date(2014, 0), 1000, 400],
    [new Date(2015, 0), 1170, 460],
    [new Date(2016, 0), 660, 1120],
    [new Date(2017, 0), 1030, 540]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-container'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    chart.getContainer().innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Comment: I cannot use the "new Date" function. I am retrieving my data as a 2D array via an ajax request.  Although I have tried formatting the date in many, many different formats, including literally "Date(yyyy,mm,dd)", it still does not recognize the date as a date.  I thought by specifying the type in the header, that would help, but it is definitely ignoring the header.  I know this because if I remove my "title" parameter from the options, it does not use the label provided in the header row and there are no labels on the scales whatsoever.

Comment: the legend labels come from the data table column headings. the title can only be set in the options. as for supplying an actual date, you will either need to 1) use the json data table constructor, as found [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam). this will allow you to use the [date string representation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#dates-and-times-using-the-date-string-representation) --> `"Date(2014, 0)"` -- OR -- 2) you will need to manipulate the data on the client before loading the data table...